# How to make GROUP BY in a cypher query?

Tags: sql, neo4j, group-by, cypher

I want to translate a SQL query to cypher. Please, is there any solution to make GROUP BY in cypher?

```
    SELECT dt.d_year, 
           item.i_brand_id          brand_id, 
           item.i_brand             brand, 
           Sum(ss_ext_discount_amt) sum_agg 
    FROM   date_dim dt, 
   store_sales, 
   item 
    WHERE  dt.d_date_sk = store_sales.ss_sold_date_sk 
    AND store_sales.ss_item_sk = item.i_item_sk 
    AND item.i_manufact_id = 427 
    AND dt.d_moy = 11 
    GROUP  BY dt.d_year, 
      item.i_brand, 
      item.i_brand_id 
   ORDER  BY dt.d_year, 
      sum_agg DESC, 
      brand_id;
```

Comment: Cyper implicitly performs group by; no need to type "group by", just order your columns and include your aggregating function(s).

Comment: I didn't know that, Thank you!

Comment: Here is the Cypher ref sheet => https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Cypher, GROUP BY is done implicitly by all of the [aggregate functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/). In a WITH/RETURN statement, any columns not part of an aggregate will be the GROUP BY key.

So for example in

```
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN COUNT(n), n.name, n.age
```

The count will count all nodes that have the same name and age. If I instead do

```
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN COUNT(n), n.name, MIN(n.age), MAX(n.age)
```

I will get the count of how many people have the same name, as well as the age range for that name.

Comment: Just a heads up, I have seen at least one version of Neo4j (not sure which, 3.3 or so) not properly aggregate if the keys come after the aggregating function. So `RETURN count(n), n.name, n.age` might not behave as expected. Might want to use `RETURN n.name, n.age, count(n)` just in case.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a limited predictive group (like an `enum` or so)
you can use the following technique

```
UNWIND RANGE (1, 10) AS i
WITH COLLECT({ Val: i % 3 }) AS Item
RETURN REDUCE (
    acc = {}, 
    x IN Item | acc {
            .*, 
            V0: CASE x.Val WHEN 0 THEN coalesce(acc.V0 + 1, 1) ELSE acc.V0 END,
            V1: CASE x.Val WHEN 1 THEN coalesce(acc.V1 + 1, 1) ELSE acc.V1 END,
            V2: CASE x.Val WHEN 2 THEN coalesce(acc.V2 + 1, 1) ELSE acc.V2 END 
        }) AS grouping
```

Another option is:

```
UNWIND RANGE(1,15) AS i
  WITH i % 4 AS mod, 1 AS unit
  RETURN DISTINCT mod, count(unit) as unit
```